# Groovy spring boot project with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring, groovy, spring-boot

I am following [this](https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fspring.io%2Fguides%2Fgs%2Fspring-boot-cli-and-js%2F&h=jAQFLZPQz) guide's structure.

I have added a script.js file (currently placed in the templates directory). This script.js is referenced from one of my html files, however when i start my application the script.js is not being found successfully.

From what i'm seeing i think you need to @Grab it somehow? Not sure.

How can i make it that my script.js file is discoverable?

---

**Edit:**

Here is a quicker view of my structure

- src

  - My.java
- templates

  - greeting.html
  - script.js
- app.groovy

greeting.html contains `<script src="script.js" />` however it is not being loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [user guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content): if the resource is static you could try putting static content in one of the standard locations (e.g. `classpath:static/` or `classpath:public/`).

If you need it to be a template (not sure thymeleaf can handle that easily) then you would have to change the view resolver configuration, but my guess is that's not the problem.